# Highlighting text at specific location from IntelliJ plugin

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am developing an IntelliJ plugin and trying to highlight text programmatically at specific line and column but facing the following issue: the actual column in IntelliJ changes depending on the tab size in its configuration. Therefore column index of the specific location can change without any changes performed in the edited text.
In Eclipse for example tab is always counted as one character.

Can you point me to some example of how to highlight a specific code location independent of the configured tab size?

Currently it is implemented like this:

```java
private static void showPsiFile(Project project, PsiFile file, int lineNumber, int column, int length) {
    OpenFileDescriptor desc = new OpenFileDescriptor(project, file.getVirtualFile(), lineNumber - 1, column);
    desc.navigate(true);

    Editor editor = FileEditorManager.getInstance(project).getSelectedTextEditor();
    int caretLocation = editor.getCaretModel().getOffset();
    int startOffset = caretLocation;
    int endOffset = startOffset + length;

    for (RangeHighlighter highlighter : editor.getMarkupModel().getAllHighlighters()) {
        highlighter.dispose();
    }

    editor.getMarkupModel().addRangeHighlighter(startOffset, endOffset, HighlighterLayer.ERROR, codeHighlightTextAttributes, HighlighterTargetArea.EXACT_RANGE);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us how you compute/retrieve the text range to highlight?

Comment: The startOffset and endOffset variables in your example are offsets into the document text. They do not depend on the tab size in any way.

Comment: @yole That's exactly the problem I am trying to solve. addRangeHighlighter method counts spaces at the beginning of line and converts tabs to equivalent number of spaces according to IntelliJ configuration. Since startOffset and endOffset don't depend  on the tab size a wrong position of code becomes highlighted.

Comment: No it does not do that. As I said, the offsets it uses point into the document text, where tabs are not expanded. Where does the 'column' value in your code come from?